# Remote usage to better unit as headless

Tags: multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I have a great HP Z2 G5 work station connected to 4k 55" TV that I use.

#### Scenario

But sometimes I remote in using TS/RDP (remote desktop) from my old reliable Dell E6410 with Windows 10 Pro (back from 2010). And sometimes connect another monitor or use my docking station setup with multiple monitors. When I do that, which machines hardware is being used, and for what purposes e.g. CPU, RAM, graphics, etc. The Z2 has Nvidia T1000

Or if I use teamviewer or gotomypc, I always wonder what machines resources are being used for what.

Is it possible someone can point me to where I need to go to research and find out this info? Frustrating that I can't seem to find it all in 1 source.

I know a lot of stuff being in IT over 2 decades, excellent level 1/2/3 tech in many regards and technologies and applications. BUT NOT THAT, just not something I've studied. Used plenty, but not by total understanding it.

How can I learn what's being done by which machine? And how to find bottlenecks?

[image]

Comment: Portions of all machines are getting used.  Whats the point of the question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.